# Strip string for safe CSS class name?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I have an arbitrary string that comes from a database. I want to place this string as an HTML class name on a web page. I am not sure what characters to expect. How can I remove the spaces and special characters to make it "safe" to be a CSS class name?

After some research, it seems space and these characters need to be remove:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^`{|}~
```

What is the best way to remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448981/what-characters-are-valid-in-css-class-names) thread to get a better understanding of valid CSS names.

I recommended a utility function as below, you should test/change the regex expression as needed.

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"[!""#$%&'()\*\+,\./:;<=>\?@\[\\\]^`{\|}~ ]");
string outputString = re.Replace(inputString, string.Empty);
```

Comment: This does not seem to remove spaces, how can this be adjusted?

Comment: @TruMan1 - Updated my original answer with the correct regex syntax. Had to escape the special characters ([reference](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)). Hope this helps.

Comment: For reference, in case someone might find it useful, here's the same regex approach in JavaScript, modified to insert a dash for each subsequence of forbidden characters:
var outputString = inputString.replace(/[!"#$%&'()\\*\+,\./:;<=>\?@\\[\\\\]^`{\|}~ ]+/g, '-');

Answer (score 0):

You are try System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars to filter out special characters:

```
var tagName = "fo@3do@11~1298#bar";
    var invalidChars = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
    var cleanTagName = new string(tagName.Where(m => !invalidChars.Contains(m)).ToArray<char>());
```

Comment: Invalid filename characters and invalid CSS class name characters are not equivalent sets. For example, `+` is allowed in filenames, but not CSS class names.